# Creating pie chart with some arcs more than 180 degrees

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, raphael, trigonometry

I'm taking help from the code given here http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/creating-a-svg-pie-chart-html5/ to create a pie chart. But the problem is, if I replace some of those values with 0. Or give large values, the angles become more than 180 and the chart looks weird as given here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x363b/7/).
The x2 and y2 values for the arc is given here

```
    x2 = parseInt(200 + 180 * Math.cos(Math.PI * endAngle / 180), 10);
    y2 = parseInt(200 + 180 * Math.sin(Math.PI * endAngle / 180), 10);
```

Is there some changes I could bring in this? Some useful tips on creating arcs with more than 180deg angles would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the largeArc flag to 1 if the angle is > 180. Change your fiddle Like so...

```
var d = "M200,200  L" + x1 + "," + y1 + "  A180,180 0 " + ((endAngle - startAngle > 180) ? 1 : 0) + ",1 " + x2 + "," + y2 + " z"; //1 means clockwise
```

Comment: Thank you! Spot on solution as always @Robert Longson!